# Parsing JSON to highcharts - Data gathered using AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, parsing, dynamic, highcharts

My JSON looks like

```
[{"target": "sumSeries(integral(org.example.fib.hi.value),integral(org.example.fib.hi1.value))", 
"datapoints": 
    [
        [2, 1359214560], 
        [3, 1359215040], 
        [4, 1359215050], 
        [null, 1359215060], 
        [null, 1359215070], 
        [5, 1359215080], 
        [7, 1359215090], 
        [9, 1359215100], 
        [10, 1359215110], 
        [null, 1359215120], 
        [10, 1359215130], 
        [14, 1359215140], 
        [null, 1359215150]
    ]}
]
```

I am trying to grab this data from my localhost and have highcharts render a line graph. 
I have something like :

```
$(function() {

$.getJSON('http://localhost/render?target=sumSeries(integral(org.example.fib.*.value))&from=-10minutes&format=json', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                yDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});

});
```

How can I parse this data?

Comment: check this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9sVF8/1/. You can add retrieving the data from your localhost part to it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use timestamps (as second parameter in JSON), so data should be parsing to display as datetime. If yes, you should revert your data parameters in JSON, and multiply timestamps by 1000 (javascript timestamps format). Example of parsing:

```
var tmpdata = [],
        i = 0,
        len = data[0].datapoints.length;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        tmpdata[i] = [data[0].datapoints[i][1]*1000,data[0].datapoints[i][0]];
    }
```

and then in series data:

```
series : [{
        name : 'AAPL',
        data : tmpdata,
        tooltip: {
            yDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
```